# jQuery - How do you select children of children when in the context of 'this'?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, children

On rolling over a wrapper div, I need different nested children to do different things.

One div needs to fade to one level of opacity, another div needs to do another thing.

It's all wrapped in quite a lot of stuff that i can't tamper with.

I have NO idea how to call children in children.... I have tried every frikkin combo of jQuery but it just does not want to play, because it's getting hitched on the 'this' part of the function.

But if I take away the 'this' it does the action to all instances in the document.

```
<div class="vpMedia"><li><a href="http://site.com"><div class="vpArrow"><image src="http://site.com/image1"></div><div class="vpLeft">Title</div><div class="vpRight">
<div class="vpRightImg"><image src="http://site.com/image2"></div></div></a></li></div>
```

I've searched everywhere for questions or topics related to finding a *child in a child* but alas, there is really nothing around. I've seen nothing like:

```
this.children(.foo).children(#bar)
```

Or maybe going this route?

```
this > .foo > #bar
```

Because it would never work, the 'this' needs to be *out* of quotation marks. So whats the solution if we cant use em?

Edit - OK so this is a really newbie question. Sorry, hopefully will help a beginner out there somewhere. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Please show us your *real* code.

Comment: Can you provide a small snippet of the JS code you are having issues with?

Comment: The snippet just looked so wrong, it was not worth sharing!

Comment: You are not specifying the class name, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call children of children you can do:

```
$(this).children(".foo").children("#bar");
```

or you can use `find` which is similar to `children` except that it [scans the DOM recursively](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

```
$(this).find("#bar");
```

Comment: WORKED! Thanks :-)
I love this find selector

Comment: Keep in mind that the `find` in not the most efficient method as it is recursive. If searching for a ID, which should be unique, I would do at @AKX said above.

Answer (score 2):

Tried `$(".foo>#bar", this)` or `$(this).children('.foo').children('#bar')`?

Also, remember that legally IDs should be unique within a page, so that example could be written just `$('#bar')`...

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `.children('.vpLeft')` , not `.children('vpLeft')`. You are selecting an element whose nodeName === 'vpLeft'.

```
$("div .vpMedia").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).children("li").children("a").children(".vpLeft").animate({opacity: .3}, { duration: 100, queue: false });
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).children("li").children("a").children(".vpLeft").animate({opacity: 1}, { duration: 100, queue: false });
})
```

You can shorten it..

```
$("div .vpMedia").mouseover(function() {
    $('>li>a>.vpLeft', this).animate({opacity: .3}, { duration: 100, queue: false });
}).mouseout(function() {
    $('>li>a>.vpLeft', this).animate({opacity: 1}, { duration: 100, queue: false });
})
```

Also it's `<img>` not `<image>`

Answer (score 0):

I believe $(this).find() will work for this.

Check out http://api.jquery.com/find/ for more information on find.